# Use C++ dll in C#(WPF)

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I had one C++ project written in MFC and some of the project are of DLL type. I wanted to use those dll in my C# code(using `DllImport`).

I tried to add as a reference but could not able to and getting an error. Do i need to copy those dll's in any of particular location? How my code is going to link those dll's?

Comment: C++ does not have standardized ABI which means C++ dlls aren't even compatible between different C++ compilers. What makes you think it'll have any chance of working under C#? You'll either have to flatten it into a C API or write wrappers or shims around the C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a reference to a native DLL. In `DllImport` you just import the DLL at runtime so be careful with the path to the DLL if it is not in the same directory as your managed application.

A problem with C++-DLLs is, that the function names in that DLLs can be decorated so you have to find out that decorated name before using it.